# JS how to extract object keys

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object which looks like this:

```
var room = {"a":
    [
        {room: "1.2.1"},
        {room: "1.2.2"},
        {room: "1.2.3"}
    ],
    1.2: [
        {room: "1.3.1"},
        {room: "1.3.2"},
        {room: "1.3.3"}
    ]};
```

I only want to read the object's properties which are `a` and `1.2` and put it into a variable.

For example:

```
var oname = room.getName();
output:
a
1.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var keys = Object.keys(room)
```

Then `keys` will have `["a","1.2"]` as value.

Also, you have a dict where its values are arrays, not an array itself.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function getRoomName(r){
    var names="";
    for (var prop in r) {
        names+=prop+"\n";
    }
    return names;
}

console.log(getRoomName(room));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try like following.

In Below snippet for in loop will iterate over object properties.

```js
var room = {"a":
                  [
                     {room: "1.2.1"},
                     {room: "1.2.2"},
                     {room: "1.2.3"}
                 ],
            1.2: [
                    {room: "1.3.1"},
                    {room: "1.3.2"},
                    {room: "1.3.3"}
                ]};

$(function(){
    for(obj in room)
    {
        //debugger;
        document.write(obj)
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```